# How can I pass down props through Route and container component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Here is the summary of component structure.

**ListItemComponent component** contains **SubwayFormView component** which shows up a modal when I click a button on a screen.

**SubwayFormView component** connects **FormContainer component** through Route and another component, **FormComponent component** is connected to **FormContainer componen**t with connect function.

Here is the code :

**ListItemComponent Component**

```
 <ModalBody>
    <SubwayFormView title={'Edit Subway Line'} editName={subway.name} editImage={subway.image} />
 </ModalBody>
```

**SubwayFormView Component**

```
 public render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={this.history}>
          <div>
            <Route path={'/SubwayLine'} component={FormContainer} />
          </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
```

**FormContainer Component**

```
const SubwayLineReduxForm = reduxForm({
  form: EDIT_SUBWAYLINE_REDUX_FORM,
  onSubmit,
  validate,
  initialValues: { imageDir: uuidv4() },
})(FormComponent);

const selector = formValueSelector(EDIT_SUBWAYLINE_REDUX_FORM);

const mapStateToProps = (state: IConsultScheduleViewStore, ownProps: IFormContainerProps) => ({
  createSubwayLineList: state.createSubwayLineList,
  updateSubwayLineList: state.updateSubwayLineList,
  val: selector(state, 'imageDir'),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => ({
  loadSubwayLine: (id: string) => dispatch(loadSubwayLine(id)),
  setSubwayLine: () => dispatch(setSubwayLine()),
  initializeSubwayLineForm: (data: Partial<IConsultDto>) => dispatch(initialize(EDIT_SUBWAYLINE_REDUX_FORM, data)),
  ...bindActionCreators({ push }, dispatch),
});

const mergeProps = (stateProps: any, dispatchProps: any, ownProps: any) => ({
  ...ownProps, ...stateProps, ...dispatchProps,
});

const FormContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  mergeProps,
)(SubwayLineReduxForm);
```

**FormComponent Component**

```
<SubtitleWrapper>
   <h5>Edit Subway Line</h5>
</SubtitleWrapper>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} role="form">
          <ContentWrapper>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                <InputField
                  name="subwayLineName"
                  component={input}
                  {...{
                    label: 'Subway Line',
                    type: 'text',
                    placeholder: 'Please enter a Subway Line.',
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </ContentWrapper>
      </form>
```

**FormComponent Component** is the place where I want to show all the information that gets from **ListItemComponent Component** as props but it is quite hard to figure out how to pass props through Route in **SubwayFormView Component** and connect function in **FormContainer Component** to **FormComponent Component**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use render in SubwayFormView Component like that

```
<Route path={'/SubwayLine'} render={() => <FormContainer prop={propName} />} />
```